# I have 2 tables in sql named as customer and account. I want to fetch all the details of a row based on id of customer table using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 2 tables in sql named as customer and account. I want to fetch all the details of a row based on id of customer table .It is giving me the following exception. Help me to resolve the code.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? UNION SELECT * FROM customer RIGHT JOIN account ON customer.id = account.custo' at line 1

String query = "SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN account ON customer.id = account.customer_id WHERE customer.id = ? UNION SELECT * FROM customer RIGHT JOIN account ON customer.id = account.customer_id WHERE customer.id = ?";